# Always show remaining time in VLC

Tags: windows, vlc-media-player

Is there a way to automatically show the remaining time of a track instead of the complete duration in VLC? I added a second counter, inverted it to show the remaining time, but the next time I started VLC, it showed the length of the track again, so I would have to click it every time I start VLC. Is there an automatic way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is a new feature, but you can (now?) add the confusingly named element "Time", which is exactly what I wanted: The remaining and the total time together.

It can be found at <kbd>Tools</kbd>-><kbd>Customize interface</kbd>, where it can be added to the two lines of the main toolbar, to the time toolbar, the advanced widget and the fullscreen controls. I personally replaced the "Total/remaining time" element with it, but it can go anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the question and your follow-up answer.  I am trying to do the exact same thing (i.e., I'd like to see both the (1) elapsed time and (2) remaining time.  Can you please clarify / elaborate on what you mean by "add the ... element Time"?  (In other words, what menu / preference item is used to do this?)  Many thanks.

Comment: @Dan7119 I edited the answer.

Comment: Fabian - Perfect, thank you very much for following up -- works great.

Comment: Any idea how to do this on macos?

Comment: Macros? Since when does VLC have those? And what would you want to do with it?

Comment: I misread the comment in 2020. It's "MacOS", not "macros". Capitalisation helps! Anyway, no, I do not know how to open the "customise interface" menu on MacOS, but surely you must have the "Media"/"Playback"/"Audio"/… menu bar somewhere, right? The "Tools" menu is one of those.

Answer (score 18):

You don't need to add a counter. You only need to single-click the time at the end of the progress bar and it will change to show remaining time.

Comment: I know, but I want both. To be exact, I want the time from start, the time until the end AND the complete time. But it seems like VLC just has one saved setting for the end/complete timer and I can't get it to keep showing both.

Comment: I see what you mean now, unfortunately can't help you there, good luck

Answer (score 2):

Catalina OSX version required two steps to toggle between displaying a stopwatch or s countdown time:

1. Click the the time display with the mouse
2. Click the slider bar

It would be easier + preferable (and less confusing) if the second step was not required.